# Difference in values of tf-idf matrix using scikit-learn and hand calculation

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, tf-idf

I am playing with `scikit-learn` to find the `tf-idf` values.

I have a set of `documents` like:

```
D1 = "The sky is blue."
D2 = "The sun is bright."
D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright."
```

I want to create a matrix like this:

```
   Docs      blue    bright       sky       sun
   D1 tf-idf 0.0000000 tf-idf 0.0000000
   D2 0.0000000 tf-idf 0.0000000 tf-idf
   D3 0.0000000 tf-idf tf-idf tf-idf
```

So, my code in `Python` is:

```
import nltk
import string

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

train_set = ["sky is blue", "sun is bright", "sun in the sky is bright"]
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

transformer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)

t1 = transformer.fit_transform(train_set).todense()
print t1
```

The result matrix I get is:

```
[[ 0.79596054  0.          0.60534851  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.4472136   0.          0.89442719]
 [ 0.          0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027]]
```

If I do a hand calculation then the matrix should be:

```
            Docs  blue      bright       sky       sun
            D1    0.2385    0.0000000  0.0880    0.0000000
            D2    0.0000000 0.0880     0.0000000 0.0880
            D3    0.0000000 0.058      0.058     0.058
```

I am calculating like say `blue` as `tf` = `1/2 = 0.5` and `idf` as `log(3/1) = 0.477121255`. Therefore `tf-idf = tf*idf = 0.5*0.477 = 0.2385`. In this way, I am calculating the other `tf-idf` values. Now, I am wondering, why I am getting different results in the matrix of hand calculation and in the matrix of Python? Which gives the correct results? Am I doing something wrong in hand calculation or is there something wrong in my Python code?

Answer (score 14):

There are two reasons:

1. You are neglecting **smoothing** which often occurs in such cases
2. You are assuming logarithm of base 10

According to [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py) sklearn does not use such assumptions.

First, it smooths document count (so there is no `0`, ever):

```
df += int(self.smooth_idf)
n_samples += int(self.smooth_idf)
```

and it uses natural logarithm (`np.log(np.e)==1`)

```
idf = np.log(float(n_samples) / df) + 1.0
```

There is also default `l2` normalization applied. In short, scikit-learn does much more "nice, little things" while computing tfidf. None of these approaches (their or yours) is bad. Their is simply more advanced.

Comment: I am wondering then why the difference in ratios is different. The difference in all the values of both the matrices cannot be represented by any multiplication or division.

Comment: my answer gives you an answer also for this. Smoothing is not just "different multiplication" neither is different logarithm base in idf part

Answer (score 0):

> smooth_idf : boolean, default=True

Smoothed version idf is used.  There are many versions. In python, the following version is used: $1+ log( (N+1)/n+1))$, where $N$ the number of total number of documents, and $n$ the number of documents containing the term.

```
tf : 1/2, 1/2
idf with smoothing: (log(4/2)+1) ,(log(4/3)+1)
tf-idf : 1/2* (log(4/2)+1) ,1/2 * (log(4/3)+1)
L-2 normalization: 0.79596054 0.60534851
```

By the way, the 2nd in the original problem maybe wrong, which should be the same.
[my out put from python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLfBl.png)